# Mixed tenses (present & past)

Tags: grammar, tenses, past-tense, present-tense

I am really upset now, experts. I said there were two acceptable answers to the following, but my superiors said there was only one. Below is the question.

I really wanted to talk to him in person, but he was not available at that moment. His servant said he was working. She gave me his number, but I (don't/didn't) want the number. I know he doesn't like being called during working hours.
*the bracketed one is the question.

Comment: You started out in the past tense (what you *wanted* to do), but finished using present tense (what you *know* about what he *likes*). There's nothing inherently wrong with that (your "superiors" are simply mistaken), and it's ***entirely*** a stylistic choice whether you make that tense switch within the *third* sentence, or leave it until the *last* one. You didn't want the number when it was given you, and you *still* don't want it at time of speaking about this later, so either tense is fine.

Comment: ...you could of course sidestep the issue by sticking with past tense: *...but I **didn't** want the number. I **knew** he **didn't** like being called during working hours* is fine. It's really a matter of what nuance you want to impart. Are you primarily interested in *recounting past events*, or *describing your current circumstances?*

Comment: Great FumbleFingers! ur argument is just like mine :) I really hate it when I am forced to teach their way though it is completely wrong.

Comment: Well, as I said, you could just use past tense throughout. Then at least there'd be no reason to argue about *how / when* to switch to present tense. Could it be that your superiors (teachers?) are particularly bothered because you've made the switch *within* a single sentence? There's nothing wrong with that, but you could just avoid doing it to keep the peace! :)

Comment: I think "your superiors" may have reacted the way I did first time I read this through – thinking that you intend the present form in the last two sentences as historical present, in which case it'd be wrong. But like FumbleFingers points out, it could just as well be that the last two sentences actually refer to "now". So, the answer to your question depends on that: do you intend the latter two as historical present (in line with the joke "A man walks into a bar...") or as "normal" present, referring to "now"?

Comment: FumbleFingers, I have actually screenshot your answer and sent it to one of the superiors of mine :)

Comment: Hannah, well, what I said to my superiors was that both answers were right because it was unclear whether the speaker referred only to his not wanting it in the past, or his still not wanting it (till now)

Comment: @FadliSheikh You are correct. Either tense is fine. It depends entirely on how you *interpret* what is being said. To say that only one is right is no different than saying that eggs taste terrible. That's simply a matter of opinion. There is no objectively *correct* answer, such that the other is unacceptable in every case.

Comment: "Hannah, well, what I said to my superiors was that both answers were right because it was unclear whether the speaker referred only to his not wanting it in the past, or his still not wanting it (till now)" Then you are perfectly right :)